# My form does not show up in the view -Ruby on Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, erb

I do not know why my form is not showing up in my views. I have a form and I am using the chosen-rails gem to allow choosing existing users and assign them a task.
My form however does not show up in the views and I am not getting an error. I just don t know what s wrong.
Here is my form:

```
<div class="invitations">
<%= form_tag assignments_path, method: :post do |f| %>
<div class="form-group">
<%= label_tag 'user_id', 'Choose Freelancer' %>
<%= f.association :user_id, 
              collection: User.all,
              include_blank: false,
              input_html: { class: 'chosen-select' }
%>
</div>
<%= submit_tag 'Assign', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
<br>
</div>
```

Comment: r u sure, u r on right page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="invitations">
 <%= form_tag assignments_path, method: :post do%>
   <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag 'user_id', 'Choose Freelancer' %>
    <%= collection_select(:user_id,User.all,:id,:name) %>
   </div>
 <%= submit_tag 'Assign', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
<br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `form_tag` [helper method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) block does not take parameters so you cannot do `f.association` You may also want to move the div with `form-group` above the form tag so it encloses the actual tag and styles it.